# Creación de componentes en Fragmentos dinámicos Android Studio

Tags: android, bucles, android-viewpager

Estoy haciendo una app en android que busca preguntas en una base de datos, al encontrar la cantidad de preguntas, genera un `Viewpager` con un arreglo con la cantidad de preguntas y en cada "página" arroja una pregunta. 
Eso ya lo hace quitando el CICLO FOR en `Fragment getItem(int position)`, pero además, por cada pregunta debe generar un componente diferente acorde a cada pregunta, la problemática está en que cuando intento llamar a los componentes por cada elemento del pager, se me cicla la aplicación, creo ques estoy haciendo mal algo en el ciclo FOR, e investigado tutoriales en internet acerca de este ciclo, pero no le encuentro solución, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Este es mi código:

```
public class ActivityQuestion extends FragmentActivity implements FragmentSwipe.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private ImageView logoImage;
    ArrayList<Question> questionsArray;
    ArrayList<Answer> answerArray;
    DrawComponents drawComponents;
    DrawVideo drawVideo;
    DrawPhoto drawPhoto;
    DrawFirm firm;
    DrawDateHour calendar;
    DrawAudioComponent audioComponent;
    DatabaseHelper dbconnection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);
        logoImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileLogo);
        questionsArray = new ArrayList<Question>();
        answerArray = new ArrayList<Answer>();
        drawComponents = new DrawComponents();
        calendar = new DrawDateHour();
        firm = new DrawFirm();
        audioComponent = new DrawAudioComponent();
        drawVideo = new DrawVideo();
        drawPhoto = new DrawPhoto();
        dbconnection= new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
       //esta linea está mal

        if(!SaveSharedPreference.getStringKeyValue(this, SaveSharedPreference.KEY_ORGANIZATION_IMAGE_PATH).equals("")){
            Bitmap b = SaveSharedPreference.loadImageFromStorage(SaveSharedPreference.getStringKeyValue(this, SaveSharedPreference.KEY_ORGANIZATION_IMAGE_PATH), SaveSharedPreference.ORGANIZATION_NAME);
            if(b != null){
                logoImage.setImageBitmap(b);
            }
        }//eliminar hasta aquí si truena

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);

        Intent params = getIntent();
        String idform = params.getStringExtra("idForm");

        getQuestionsbyFormId(Long.parseLong(idform));

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        //Todo hasta aquí para generar el viewPager
    }
    public void getQuestionsbyFormId(long id)
    {
        Cursor cursorAns;
        Cursor c = dbconnection.readQuest(id);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Question question = new Question();
            question.setId_question(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id_question")));
            question.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("question")));

            cursorAns = dbconnection.readAnswerbyQuestionId(Long.parseLong(question.getId_question()));

            while (cursorAns.moveToNext())
            {
                Answer answer = new Answer();
                answer.setId_answer_type(cursorAns.getString(cursorAns.getColumnIndex("id_answer_type")));
                answerArray.add(answer);
            }
            question.setAnswers(answerArray);
            questionsArray.add(question);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction() {

        }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            //método del swipe para pasar entre preguntas
            FragmentSwipe fragment = new FragmentSwipe();
            fragment.setQuestion(questionsArray.get(position).getQuestion());
            //Draw elements
            for (int i = 0; i < questionsArray.get(position).getAnswers().size() ; i++)
             {
                     if (answerArray.equals(1))
                     {
                         drawComponents.setTextLine();
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        if (answerArray.equals(2))
                        {
                            drawComponents.setParrafo();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (answerArray.equals(3))
                            {
                                drawComponents.setDirection();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (answerArray.get(position).equals(4))
                                {
                                    drawComponents.setEmail();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (answerArray.equals(5))
                                    {
                                        drawComponents.setTel();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (answerArray.equals(6))
                                        {
                                            drawComponents.setCel();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if (answerArray.equals(7))
                                            {
                                                drawComponents.setTextArea();
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                if (answerArray.equals(8))
                                                {
                                                    drawComponents.setList();
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    if (answerArray.equals(9))
                                                    {
                                                        drawComponents.setListSelection();
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        if (answerArray.equals(10))
                                                        {
                                                            drawComponents.setCheck();
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            if (answerArray.equals(11))
                                                            {
                                                                drawComponents.setRadio();
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                if (answerArray.equals(12))
                                                                {
                                                                    drawComponents.setNumber();
                                                                }
                                                                else {
                                                                    if (answerArray.equals(13))
                                                                    {
                                                                        calendar.setDate();
                                                                    }
                                                                    else
                                                                    {
                                                                        if (answerArray.equals(14))
                                                                        {
                                                                            calendar.setHour();
                                                                        }
                                                                        else
                                                                        {
                                                                            if (answerArray.equals(15))
                                                                            {
                                                                                calendar.setDate();
                                                                                calendar.setHour();
                                                                            }
                                                                            else
                                                                            {
                                                                                if (answerArray.equals(16))
                                                                                {
                                                                                    drawComponents.setHipervinculo();
                                                                                }
                                                                                else
                                                                                {
                                                                                    if (answerArray.equals(18))
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        //firm.setCanvas();
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    else
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        if (answerArray.equals(19))
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            drawPhoto.Image();
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        else
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            if (answerArray.equals(20))
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                //AGREGAR EL MÉTODO DEL VIDEO
                                                                                                drawVideo.Video();
                                                                                            }
                                                                                            else
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                if (answerArray.equals(21))
                                                                                                {
                                                                                                    audioComponent.Recorder();
                                                                                                }
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                     }

             }


            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return questionsArray.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema no es que el `for` quede en un ciclo infinito, la forma en que lo armas esta correcta. 
El problema son los `if` que estan dentro, estas comparando un `ArrayList<Answer>` con un `Int`.

Primero, si usas un for para recorrer un array deberias usar el `i` del indice para obtener el objeto especifico del array con el cual vas a trabajar

```
for(...){
   Answer answer = answerArray.get(i);
}
```

Algo mas que note en el codigo es la anidacion excesiva de `ifs` en casos como esto queda mucho mejor que uses `else if` o incluso mejor seria que uses un `Swich` con sus respectivos `case`

Por lo que entiendo de tu codigo y lo que explicas, por cada tipo de respuesta debe generar un componente distinto, En ese caso, imagino que la solucion iria mas por este lado:

```
for(int i = 0; i < questionsArray.get(position).getAnswers().size() ; i++){

   Answer answer = answerArray.get(i);
   String answerType = answer.getId_answer_type();

   if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
      drawComponents.setTextLine();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
      drawComponents.setParrafo();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
      drawComponents.setDirection();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("4")){
      drawComponents.setEmail();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("5")){
      drawComponents.setTel();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("6")){
      drawComponents.setCel();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("7")){
      drawComponents.setTextArea();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("8")){
      drawComponents.setList();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("9")){
      drawComponents.setListSelection();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("10")){
      drawComponents.setCheck();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("11")){
      drawComponents.setRadio();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("12")){
      drawComponents.setNumber();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("13")){
      calendar.setDate();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("14")){
      calendar.setHour();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("15")){
      calendar.setDate();
      calendar.setHour();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("16")){
      drawComponents.setHipervinculo();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("17")){
      //...
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("18")){
      //...
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("19")){
      drawPhoto.Image();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("20")){
      drawVideo.Video();
   }else if(answerType.equalsIgnoreCase("21")){
      audioComponent.Recorder();
   }
}
```

De esta forma comparamos el answerType con los distintos tipos y segun sea el ejecutamos lo que corresponda. Solo asegurate de usar las constantes correctas al comparar, yo aca use 1, 2, 3, etc porque fue lo que intentaste usar, pero seguro en el proyecto deben haber constantes para definir estos tipos.

Comment: gracias, esto en verdad me ayudo, ya estaba perdida con el uso de los ciclos